# Move cursor to a specific cell and press CTRL+E programmatically

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I am using the Java Excel API to programaticaly enter data to an excel sheet and retrieve data. I need to move the cursor to a specific cell, that is select a cell in that column, and press `Ctrl+E`, to populate that column using `Excel Flash Fill` feature. I am wondering how I can do this

Comment: a quick suggestion , rather than trying to hit 'CTRL+E' programmatically i would suggest you to find the event it performs and perform that event programatically

Comment: jexcel isn't operating on a live Excel spreadsheet, but on its own internal data structures. What do you expect Cttl+E to do, if you were to get it working?